# Google Forms: Auto-update sheet from submitted responses

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

Response are automatically added to the sheet "Form Responses". I want to apply certain formulas in a sheet called "Student Answers". However, "Student Answers" doesn't auto-update from the submitted responses. Here are the formulas I am trying to use:

`='Form Responses'!A1` etc.
`=IF('Form Responses'!E6='Answers'!$E$2,1,0)` "Answers" is another sheet with an answer key
`=SUM(D5:I5)` this sums the numbers given in the previous formula.

Basically, I have created a quiz, and I want to grade the quiz on a separate sheet. Here is [the Sheet in question](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqvTp4ajjRSUdGlQNDV5cUd4TVFmeFB3TndJeTBLblE&usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use =ARRAYFORMULA.
Here are my working examples:

`=ArrayFormula('Student Submissions'!A:C)` for basic copying of columns

`=ARRAYFORMULA(If('Student Submissions'!D3:D='Student Submissions'!D3,1,0))` for IF statements

`=ArrayFormula(mmult(D3:I;TRANSPOSE(sign(column(D3:I)))))` for SUM

`=ARRAYFORMULA(J3:J/6*100)` for AVERAGE and percent

*Note: I found these answers in the Google Product forums but cannot find the link again.*